# Not able to run git diff within shell script with local variable

Tags: shell, sh

I am amateur shell script coder, below shell script I am trying to do the `git diff` and `git add`

but I am not able to print the `$a` and `git diff $a` not working as expected.

```
#!/bin/sh

GITSTATUS=($(git status))

for x in ${!GITSTATUS[@]}; do
        if [[ "${GITSTATUS[$x]}" == *"modified"* ]]; then
                a=`echo ${GITSTATUS[$x]} | sed 's/modified://'`
                echo "Modified file :$a" ## <-- Does not show filename
                git diff $a              ## <-- Does not operate correctly
                echo "Do you want to add this file: (Y/n)"
        fi
done
```

Let me know how to use the variable with command.

Comment: You're trying to use arrays with `/bin/sh`. That's not an available feature in POSIX sh; you'll need to use ksh or bash instead.

Comment: BTW, don't use `**` and such inside your code for emphasis/formatting -- use comment characters appropriate to the language at hand.

Comment: ...beyond that, `array=( $(somecommand) )` is in and of itself a bad practice, even on shells that support it: It performs not just string-splitting but also glob expansion on the output of `somecommand`. Use `read -r -a array < <(somecommand)` instead, which splits words on IFS but does *not* expand globs. Not that I'm sure there's actually a valid use case for arrays here either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three points:

1. This script is trying to use a lot of features only available in ksh or bash with a `#!/bin/sh` shebang. Even if `/bin/sh` is a link to `bash`, it runs in POSIX compatibility mode when invoked under that name. However, there's no guarantee that `/bin/sh` will be bash at all -- many systems ship `ash` or `dash`. See [Choose Your Shell](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices#Choose_Your_Shell).
2. Even on bash, your `for` loop would be iterating over *words*, not *lines*. Consequently, if `${GITSTATUS[$x]}` is `modified:`, it will contain *only* the word `modified:`, and no filename along with it. See [Don't Read Lines With For](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).
3. Don't attempt to parse the output of `git status` without the `--porcelain` options: The default output is meant for human consumption, not scripts, and can change in unpredictable ways in the future (or can be subject to output changes based on current language or locale).

   From the `git status` man page:

   > `--porcelain[=<version>]` - 
   >     Give the output in an easy-to-parse format for scripts. This is similar to the short output, but will remain stable across Git versions and regardless
   >     of user configuration. See below for details.

---

```
#!/bin/bash
topdir=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel) || exit    # find repository root
cd "$topdir" || exit                               # ...and cd to it
while IFS= read -r -d '' line <&3; do              # read NUL-delimited lines
  [[ ${line:3:1} = " " ]] || continue              # sanity-check: format is "XY filename"
  x=${line:0:1}                                    # X: index status
  y=${line:1:1}                                    # Y: working-tree status
  case $x$y in                                     # compare *both* flags: if EITHER is...
    *[CR]*) IFS= read -r -d '' _ <&3 ;;            # ...copy/rename: skip dest name
  esac
  case $y in                                       # Compare *working-tree* flag:
    *M*)    : ;;                                   # ...modify: continue loop
    *)      continue ;;                            # ...otherwise: skip to next filename
  esac
  filename=${line:3}                               # extract filename from line
  printf 'Modified file: %q\n' "$filename" >&2     # print (stderr for user interaction)
  git diff -- "$filename"                          # run git diff
  while :; do                                      # loop for a valid response
    echo "Do you want to add this file? (Y/n)" >&2 # prompt the user
    IFS= read -r answer || break                   # ...abort if read fails
    case $answer in
      [Yy]*|"") git add -- "$filename"; break;;
      [Nn]*)    break;;
      *)        echo "Response not recognized" >&2;;
    esac
  done
done 3< <(git status --porcelain -z)
```

Some key notes:

- The reason we `cd` to the top of the repository is to ensure that the paths included in `git status` are valid relative to the current directory, as required for `git diff`.
- `${line:0:1}` and `${line:1:1}` are parameter expansion operators for selecting the first and second characters. See [the bash-hackers wiki page on parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe).
- All expansions, in this code, are quoted: `"$filename"`, not `$filename`. This is essential for correctly handling files with spaces or glob characters in their names.
- Using the `-z` argument to `git status` NUL-delimits output, making the format completely unambiguous (as `NUL` is a character unable to exist in filenames).
- Using file descriptor 3 to read from `git status` enables file descriptor 0 (stdin) to remain connected to the terminal, allowing prompting.

Comment: Bizarrely, arrays are one of the things that still work, even if `bash` is invoked as `sh`.

Comment: Edited original comment to emphasize that.

Comment: @Charles I am getting below error: option `porcelain' takes no value

Comment: @Elankeeran, then you're running with an old version of `git`. Change it from `--porcelain=v1` to just `--porcelain`, or upgrade.

Comment: Thanks, @Charless. Very helpful information I will build on top this and share the code with you... I am just shell script today. It is fascinating and thanks for your great help!!

Comment: Feel free to ask if you have a question about why I wrote anything in a particular way.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy i added below code after [Nn]*) `while :; do
           read -r ans
           case $ans in
                [Yy]*|"") git checkout "$filename"; break;;
                [Nn]*) break;;
                *)     echo "Response not recognized" >&2
           esac
        done` get below error `./git-add-file.sh: line 27: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
../git-add-file.sh: line 27: `      *)  echo "Response not recognized" >&2;;'`

Comment: Could you put your modified code up on https://gist.github.com/? I'm about to go to the gym and get breakfast, but I'll take a look after.

Comment: code fixed and its working fine here is my URL https://gist.github.com/elankeeran/696b58926be31ac9ede6e89338a0a08b#file-git-add-sh

Comment: I'd suggest `git checkout -- "$filename"`, to disambiguate that the filename is just that, and not a branch, an option, or something else.